# I want to get distinct and selected column names in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get distinct of coulmn1 and the output should be selected column names(column1, column5) in mongodb

Comment: Have you tryed anything?

Comment: I can get the output of column 1 only when I using distinct function

Comment: Can you show your doc structrue and query that you make? This will help to ask on your question

Comment: ```> db.tkts.distinct('tkt_id',{tkt_name:'TEST'})
[
 "1tick",
 "2tick",
 "3tick",
 "4tick",
 "5tick",
 "6tick"
]```

Comment: You can not do that. The reason of this is that mongo do not understand which data select from similar docs.

Comment: But maybe aggregation will help you. You can push column5 values from every docs in one array